# 'packer.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: command-prompt

I installed packer and i am trying access it in command prompt but i am getting below error.
Can someone help me on this.

> 'packer.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you in the correct folder? Perhaps you should add the install folder of packer to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Yeah i am in correct folder

Answer (score 0):

If running Windows, create a folder (Packer) in  `C:\Program Files\`
Copy the `"packer.exe"` into the:  `C:\Program Files\Packer>`
Then within the above folder from the PowerShell command run:  `.\packer.exe --version`

Example:`PS C:\Program Files\Packer> .\packer.exe --version`

```
    1.5.4

    PS C:\Program Files\Packer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set PATH environment variable for the location where you had stored "packer.exe"